# how to check if the request came from mobile or computer in php

Tags: php, mobile

i need to check if the request came from a mobile phone device or desktop computer using php please help. thanks

Comment: [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/) is comprehensive but nice & easy to use.

Answer (score 16):

I am using a function to identify mobile browsers in my projects, which can detect almost all major Mobile Operating systems and browsers.

```
    function ismobile() {
    $is_mobile = '0';

    if(preg_match('/(android|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
        $is_mobile=1;
    }

    if((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
        $is_mobile=1;
    }

    $mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
    $mobile_agents = array('w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','andr','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac','blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno','ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-','maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-','newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox','qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar','sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-','tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp','wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-');

    if(in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
        $is_mobile=1;
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP'])) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) {
            $is_mobile=1;
        }
    }

    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0) {
        $is_mobile=0;
    }

    return $is_mobile;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` for mobile user agents.

You should check out http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ for already existing scripts to detect for mobile browsers (it just uses the user agents).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [The WURFL PHP API](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/nphp/) or [Tera-Wurfl](http://www.tera-wurfl.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

http://mobiledetect.net/ is another lightweight php class, but you mist keep in mind that checking User-agent is a good but not perfect way, the issue is rules are constantly out-dated and incomplete so you need to change the detection code continuously. 
Also check https://modernizr.com/ for another way to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, what do you consider "a mobile device"?

User agent parsers will give very good results, except for rare edge cases. The problem is that you have to constantly update them if you store the data locally or depend on the service being online if you use it "in the cloud".

It is better to use a functionality detection library, e.g. [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com), send to your server information about the browser capabilities on first visit and serve appropriate content based on what the browser can or cannot do. Or even better, delegate that to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop browser usually sends requests with the following header:

```
Sec-CH-UA-Mobile: ?0
```

The browser on the mobile device usually sends requests with the following header:

```
Sec-CH-UA-Mobile: ?1
```

So, you could check this using code like the following:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE']) &&
          $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE']=='?1')
{
   ...
}
```