# Determining the clients device (PC or Mobile)

Tags: html

I am returing to website development and I want my work to be as global as possible. When a web surfer arrives at my site, is there a way to determine whether he/she is surfing with a PC or mobile phone and disply the content accordingly? Or would it be better to build responsive sites using CSS?

Comment: have you checked about @media tags in css

Comment: maybe this will help out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335237/how-to-check-if-the-request-came-from-mobile-or-computer-in-php

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following questions, looks like there could be quite a lot of useful information in there for you:

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

[How to detect a mobile device with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666907/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-with-javascript)

[Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.UserAgent` because  UserAgent gets the raw user agent string of the client browser

Comment: You could expand this a little. Its not that helpful as it is