# How to stop execution of javascript if condition is true?

Tags: javascript

I want to tag my mobile visitor with a specific URL like http://www.example.com.index.html?source=mobile i used this script to redirect visitors to the given url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 800) 
{
    window.location ="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile";
}

//-->
</script>
```

But when i used this script the page kept on loading again and again so i tried to add another condition in this script but i am confused how to make the second condition to stop loading again and again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width >= 800) 
{
    window.location ="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile";
}
 Else if (document.referrer ="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile")
{
    //stop execution here
}


//-->
</script>
```

Now plz someone help me to stop execution of javascript if second condition is true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use return statement.

Comment: the second condition will never be met because the first one will have already redirected see my answer below. Thanks

Comment: I've just written you a JS code below, I am not saying this is the perfect you can get but it may work - I've tested it in my Chrome JS Console.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the statement in an anonymous function:

```
(function(){
    if (screen.width >= 800)  {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile";
    }else if (document.referrer == "http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile") {
        return;
    }
});
```

You can only use return from within a function, despite what the other answers claim.

I am also assuming that you will be adding more code beneath the if statement, otherwise there is no use in stopping execution.

A few issues with your code:

1. You spelt else with a capital E and is should be lowercase
2. in the else if statement you didn't use two equals

Both issues amended in the above code

Comment: return false will be more handy

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
if (screen.width >= 800 && document.referrer !="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile") 
{
    window.location ="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile";
}
```

The way you have it set up now will not work as the first if will always be met, you should either do as I suggest here or put the document referer condition first (plus you need == not =).

Comment: @lededje I explained why trying to terminate the script wouldn't solve his issue of constant reloads of the page and this solves that so what exactly is your point?

Comment: This answer is totally relevant, but it's not a very good solution. I tried this but it seems that Google Chrome Javascript engine continues the execution until the new page data is returned from the http channel.

Answer (score 1):

you should detect mobile browsers directly inside php/whateveryouuse, there's a lot of mobile detector scripts (checking the user agent [how to check if the request came from mobile or computer in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335237/how-to-check-if-the-request-came-from-mobile-or-computer-in-php))

the way it's now: the use enters the site, if the resolution is low he is redirected to... the same page! (loaded the site twice)

if you detect mobile serverside: the user enters the site only once <-- faster and works even if javascript is disabled

also, you should read something about responsive designs if you only care about the browser's resolution

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.href` to   get the URL

And you have a typo:`else if`.. not  `Else if`

```
 if (screen.width >= 800 && window.location.href !="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile") 
{
    window.location.href ="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile";
}
```

In context of stoping the execution,

```
else if (window.location.href ="http://www.example.com/index.html?source=mobile")
        {
            return;//to stop execution here..use return;
        }
   // This condition is unnecessary though
```

**NOTE**:There is a difference between `return true,return false and return`

**return false:** stops the event from "bubbling up".Halts the execution

**return true**:continues the execution.

**return;**

Here is a quote from the ECMA 262 standard, which JavaScript is based upon, regarding return; As noted the result is "undefined".

> An ECMAScript program is considered syntactically incorrect if it
>   contains a  return statement that is not within a FunctionBody. A
>   return statement causes a function to cease execution and return a
>   value to the caller. If  Expression is omitted, the return value is 
>   undefined. Otherwise, the return value is the value of Expression.

Comment: Capital `E` in `else`? `SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`. `return` not inside a _function_? `SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`

Comment: Also, setting `document.referrer` in an `if`? (I know it's copypasta)

Answer (score 0):

IE8, IE8+, IE11, Firefox, Chrome:

```
<script>
  ... I wana cancel here ...
  if (document.execCommand) document.execCommand('Stop');   
  if (window.stop) window.stop();   
</script>
```